# WD Calender date picker change dateformat

Tags: jquery, datepicker

```
$("#stpartdate").datepicker({ 
                        picker: "<button class='calpick'></button>", 
                        onReturn:function(d){
                                   $("#stpartdate").val(d.Format("m/d/Y"));
                                  $("#etpartdate").val(d.format('m/d/yy'));
                                  } 
                        });
```

The above code showing the following err,

```
TypeError: d.Format is not a function
$("#stpartdate").val(d.Format("m/d/Y"));
```

any help

Comment: Try to add this **dateFormat: "m/d/Y",** before the **picker: ...**

Comment: datepicker not working , as ur suggestion im using http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-plugins-demo/wdDatePicker/sample.htm

Comment: I see at the bottom of the page you mentioned that d.Format() requires 2 param: d.Format("M/d, yyyy")

Comment: that also tried same error VDesign

Comment: in that demo page also the same error occurring..